# PyMySQL where like wildcards surround a variable

Tags: python, mysql, variables, wildcard, pymysql

Here is my code:

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors

# ...

for w in aList: 
  param = w
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test where text like %(p)s", {"p": "%%{}%%".format(param)})
  result_set = cursor.fetchall()
  for row in result_set:
    print(row)
```

I got nothing executed and no error.

Unlike similar questions and answers on this site, my question is about a variable surrounded by two wildcards. This variable will change each time in the loop, rather than being a fixed string (in which case it will execute).

Many thanks in advance! Joanne

Comment: I am not getting an error.  I am doing:
```cursor.execute("SELECT * from mysql.db WHERE Host like %(p)s', {'p': '%%{}%%.format(param)')```

This returns 2.  If I change param to 'google', I get a zero back.

Comment: Can you print out what param is?

Comment: Yes, I can print the param. they are the first item, which is a string, from a tuple in a list. such as:
like
star

Comment: The thing is that if your param is a fixed string, you can get it work absolutely. But my param is a variable, which will change in the loop. That gives me nothing in the result. I think the question here is about a syntax thing about a variable appearing in the like and being surrounded by wildcards.

Comment: Don't fully understand what param is still.  My aList is [ 'localhost', 'google'] and your code works (I did change test to mysql.db and text to Host).  I think you need to evaluate what is in aList and a print statement will help.  You will probably find that it is other than a simple type (string, int, float, etc.).

Comment: I don't think that is where the problem is, because it is absolutely working for me just as you have presented it.

Comment: I think I suddenly get it work. I change the code to: SELECT * FROM test where text like %(p)s", {'p': '%%'+param+'%%'} and it suddenly works.But I have to appreciate your reminder to print the param. I think it is very debugging wise! Many thanks!

Comment: should I close or delete this question? As it is not a question any more.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pymysql
    import pymysql.cursors
     ... ... 
     for w in aList:  
         param = w 
         cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test where text like '%{$param} %')
         result_set = cursor.fetchall()
         for row in result_set:
              print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! However, this code achieve the same result as my code, which produces no result and no error.

Comment: Try this SELECT * FROM test where text like '%{}%'".format(param)

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it is still not working and getting error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'text%'' at line 1

Comment: Can you print that query with dynamic value before that execute statement ?

Comment: You want ```"select * from test where text like '{}'".format('%{0}%'.format(param))```

edit: added single quotes around the first pair of {}

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! I suddenly get it work now.

Comment: Don't use format! It's vulnerable to SQL injection!

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```py
for w in aList: 
  param = w
  cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test WHERE text LIKE %s", f"%{param}%")
  result_set = cursor.fetchall()
  for row in result_set:
    print(row)
```

Don't use `format()` of `f"SELECT ..."` since it is **vulnerable to SQL injection.**